# Can't connect to windows 8 share from any remote source. "The user name or password is incorrect." error

Tags: networking, windows-8, network-shares

I have a problem sharing my folders on local lan from one Windows 8 machine to.. practically anywhere (tried Android phone and other Windows 8 machine).

As far as I know I do everything right:
- When sharing I go to folder's *Properties*, go to *Sharing* tab, click *Share...*. I don't do anything since me (owner) is already set up and I just click *(admin)Share*.

- I can view this share on local machine by putting `\\localhost` or `\\Ares` (name of my computer) in address bar
- My sharing options *Network and Sharing Center * > * Change advanced sharing settings * are as follows:

  - Turn on network discovery
  - Turn on automatic setup of network connected devices
  - Turn on file and printer sharing
  - Allow windows to manage homegroup connections (recommended)
- I do not have homegroup and I'm on a private (home) network. I've already tried this with disabled firewall and I have no other antivirus nor firewall software installed (I'am beyond NAT) and windows *Server* service is up and running.

Yet still every time I try to connect to this windows 8 shared folder I got login prompt and after typing in `ARES\<username>` and `<password>` i got "Incorrect user name or password" error message. I've tried this also on Android phone with similiar result (only there I got connection error message).

I'm not sure if this might be related but it seems that every time I try to access share this error message is being logged in windows Event Logger:

Failed to schedule Software Protection service for re-start at 2013-11-21T19:01:24Z. Error Code: 0x80041316.

Comment: Are you able to connect using Remote Desktop from the other Windows 8 machine?

Comment: Yes I was able to log in from remote computer, after I enabled this option in *System properties* > *Remote*. Which lead me to resolving this issue

Comment: Please add your resolution as an answer, and then accept it, so that we can close this question.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't do that yet: 

Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 11/21/2013 4:16:12 AM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

I will post answer in comment here, and tommorow as normal answer

Comment: Unfortunately I kinda made fool of myself.

I tried to restrict users that are able to login into my computer to just me, and I clicked *Select users...*. It's was written there that **User already has access**.

I was thinking.. what user, and then it hit me.

Don't laugh since I've checked this like 3 times, but my username on this computer is not what it's displaying. In control panel it's written that account name is *Darnok* (local account), but the actual login is *User* (this is folder name in *C:\Users*) and also name of actual account.

Comment: It happens. At least you figured it out, and it will help people in the future with the same problem.

Comment: It can be closed now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I kinda made fool of myself.

I tried to restrict users that are able to login into my computer to just me, and I clicked *Select users...*. It's was written there that **User already has access**.

I was thinking.. what user, and then it hit me.

Don't laugh since I've checked this like 3 times, but my username on this computer is not what it's displaying. In control panel it's written that account name is *Darnok* (local account), but the actual login is *User* (this is folder name in *C:\Users*) and also name of actual account.